# Git update on Mac - bashrc

Tags: macos, git

I'm trying to upgrade my Git on my Mac.

I went through the uninstall and install process, however, I think I must have something wrong with my `.bashrc`.

When I do `git --version`, it says it is using the old, uninstalled version.  When I do `which git`, it references: `/usr/local/bin/git`

However, my `.bashrc` has the following:

```
PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
$PATH=/usr/local/rvm/bin:$PATH
$PATH=/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1
$PATH=/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
$PATH=Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin 
$PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH" 
"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

When I `cd` into the `usr/local/git/bin` and then check the version, the new version is there. Does anyone know what I need to do in my `.bashrc` to make it pick up the new version and then why the old version which is supposed to have been uninstalled, is still showing as the version?

My .bash_profile is:

```
$PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
$PATH=/usr/local/rvm/bin:$PATH
$PATH=/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1
$PATH=/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
$PATH=/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin
$PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/binexport PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/Users/mm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/mm/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/Users/mm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/mm/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

I'm afraid Spellcheck just tells me not to put the $ in front of PATH at the beginning of the lines in my .bashrc. I have removed the $ from the left of the opening PATH in each line and I still get the old version of git and a reference to the path: /usr/local/bin/git when I ask 'which_git' in my terminal.

Comment: `$PATH=...` doesn't seem right, as well as some other oddities. Is that a verbatim copy?

Comment: Yes. How do I go about finding the errors?

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/ is a great tool. What I can tell you from just looking at it is: **1** `$PATH=...`, as I mentioned (hint `$`). **2** Reassigning `$PATH` without the old value of `$PATH`. **3** The lonely `]]`.

Comment: **4** Sourcing the same file twice. **5** `Users/` that should probably be `/Users/`.

Comment: Hi Biffen, thanks for this. I'm afraid I can't understand the comments. I'm not sure what the hint in 1 is supposed to mean. I have $ in front of each line, including 1 which didn't copy correctly. I don't understand your comment on 2. I don't know why the ]][[ brackets in the 3 are in the wrong order. I'll look for where that line came of later. I don't understand which file you can see is being sourced twice. I'll try to find help on spellcheck. Thanks for that reference.

Comment: When assigning to a variable it should *not* have a `$`. Adding dirs to `$PATH` is usually done by `PATH=/some/dir/:$PATH`. Without the `:$PATH` bit at the end you'll lose whatever was in the variable before. The `]]` won't do much without corresponding `[[`. `source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` is in there twice.

Comment: so no $ in front of any of the opening PATH lines? I know re the ]][[ but that isn't my current problem with git. i'll look into that separately.

Comment: Just for testing, did you consider http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg244205.html?

Comment: Hi VonC, I had a look at that link but I'm not sure I've understood what it is or what it does. I'm having trouble upgrading my git - my bash isn't set up to uninstall the old one effectively or install the new version. Do you know how to do that? Thanks